# Как в accordion ngx bootstrap привязать класс к определенному элементу ngFor?

Tags: bootstrap, typescript, angular

Я пытаюсь менять дефолтные классы на открытый/ закрытый аккордеон бутстрапа (ngx bootstrap Accordion).
Проблема в моей реализации заключается в том, что я не привязываюсь к каждым элементам-объектам моего массива, из-за чего, при открытии аккордеона одного из элементов, css класс меняется для всех.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
 <accordion>
  <accordion-group [panelClass]="{'active':isOpen, 'passive':!isOpen}" (isOpenChange)="isOpenChange($event)">
   <span accordion-heading class="accordion-header">
    {{item.title}}
   </span>
   <div>{{item.description}} </div>
  </accordion-group>
 </accordion>
</div>
```

---

```
@Component({...})
Class CustomAccrodion {
isOpen: boolean = false;
 data = [
  { title: 'first', description: 'first text' },
  { title: 'second', description: 'first text' },
  { title: 'third', description: 'first text' },
 ];
 ...
 isOpenChange(open: boolean) {
  this.isOpen = open;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый быстрый и простой вариант - просто добавлять свойство объекту из массива `data`.

В шаблоне в метод `isOpenChange` будем передавать `item`:

```
(isOpenChange)="isOpenChange(item)"
```

В самом методе сделаем следующее:

```
public isOpenChange(item: any): void {
    // изначально свойства `isOpen` нету, поэтому `!undefined => true`
    item.isOpen = !item.isOpen;
}
```

Также немного изменим биндинг свойства:

```
[panelClass]="{ active: item.isOpen, passive: !item.isOpen }"
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! Я хотел добавить свойство массиву data, но запутался с тем, как бы это сделать.